# Bazel: add compile flags to default C++ toolchain

Tags: c++, bazel

I would like to add some compiler and linker flags to the default C++ toolchain, so that all the targets I build (local or imported) share them.

I know that can define my own toolchain, but I don't want to do that as it's very complicated and easy to get wrong.

Ideally I would like something like this:

```
cc_toolchain = cc_default_toolchain()
cc_toolchain.copts = [...]
cc_toolchain.linkopts = [...]
```

Also, I don't want to set global flags in the `.bashrc` file, as it's hard to configure per platform and it's not easy to share among different repositories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could set [`--cxxopt`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--cxxopt) and [`--linkopt`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--linkopt) in a shared `.bazelrc` file that you reference from the different projects (as sub-module or similar) or [import](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#imports) in the workspace's local `.bazelrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to copy the default generated toolchain into your project and make modifications in it.

You'd run `bazel info` to locate your `output_base` directory, and find the toolchain files there.

Source: https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/N1qvsGMJoAE