# How can I pass a specific macro to each compile in bazel?

Tags: bazel

Here's an easy version of the BUILD file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "ab",
    srcs = ['a.c', 'b.c', 'logger.h'],
)
```

`logger.h` contains the implementation of a logging function that uses the macro `XOC_FILE_ID`. `XOC_FILE_ID` has to contain the name of the source file.
Using `__FILE__` instead would not help because `__FILE__` expands to the string `"logger.h"` inside the file *logger.h*.

That's why I need to compile these files with different defines:

```
gcc -c [...] -DXOC_FILE_ID="a.c" a.c
gcc -c [...] -DXOC_FILE_ID="b.c" b.c
```

My failed approaches:

- set the attribute `local_defines` using the value`{source_file}`: `local_defines = ['XOC_FILE_ID="{source_file}"]`: does not get replaced
- set the attribute `local_defines` using the make variable `$<`: `local_defines = ['XOC_FILE_ID="$<"]`: Bazel aborts telling me that `$(<)` is not defined
- same approach for attribute `copts`

Of course, I could try to make Bazel call a compiler wrapper script. However, this would mean that I have to explicitly set PATH to my wrapper script(s) before each call to Bazel. Isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have access to `{source_file}` in a toolchain definition.

This means you have to write your own toolchain definition.
I tried two ways of writing a toolchain:

- Use the [Bazel tutorial on toolchains](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html). Afterwards my build was broken: The default compile options of Bazel were missing. `cc_library` did not create shared libraries any more.
- Use [a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64169836/601203) pointing to [a post in bazel-discuss](https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/N1qvsGMJoAE/m/GmxvJQV1AgAJ) and use the toolchain that Bazel itself creates using your environment. That's what I'm going to describe now (for Bazel 3.5.1)

1. If you want to use a compiler that is not in $PATH, do `bazel clean` and update $PATH to make compiler available. Bazel will pick it up.
2. create a toolchain directory (maybe `my-toolchain/`) in your workspace
3. `bazel build @bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain`
4. copy `BUILD`, all `*.bzl` files, `cc_wrapper.sh` and `builtin_include_directory_paths` from `$(bazel info output_base)/external/local_config_cc/` to your toolchain directory; copy the files the symbolic links are pointing to instead of copying the symbolic links
5. Adapt the `BUILD` file in `my-toolchain/` to your needs—like adding `'-DXOC_FILE_ID=\\"%{source_file}\\"'` to `compile_flags` of `cc_toolchain_config`.
6. add these lines to your `.bazelrc` to make Bazel use your new toolchain by default:

```
      build:my-toolchain --crosstool_top=//my-toolchain:toolchain
      build --config=my-toolchain
```